# Show that $K_{4,4}$ contain no subdivision of $K_5$

Tags: graph-theory

Show that $K_{4,4}$ contain no subdivision of $K_5$

Here is What I think the proof look like

Assume the contrary that $K_{4,4}$ contain a subdivision $F$ of $K_5$ let $k$ be the number of vertices of degree $2$, then we have $5$ vertices of degree $4$ and $k$ vertices of degree $2$, so

$V(F) = 5+k$

$m(F)= 10+k$

$m(K_{4,4})=16$

From here can't I jump to conclusion that $m(F)=10+k \leq 16$ so $k \leq 6$? and then $V(F) \leq 11$ but $V(K_{4,4}) =8$ ?

Comment: Your conclusions that you jump to are all correct, but there is no reason to say "but" at the end, since $V(F)\le 11$ is perfectly consistent with $V(K_{4,4})=8$.  In other words, your conclusions are correct but they do not give the "proof by contradiction" that you were hoping for -- no clear contradiction has been reached yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, $V(F)=5+k$ and $V(K_{4,4})=8$, so clearly $k$ is at most 3.

That means that **at most 3 edges of the $K_5$ have been subdivided**.

Now notice that the 5 vertices of the (original) $K_5$ must be partitioned among the two parts of the $K_{4,4}$, either as 3+2 or as 4+1.

When two vertices of the $K_5$ appear in the same part, the edge between them **must** be subdivided.

In the 3+2 case, **at least 4 edges need to be subdivided** (3 on one side and 1 on the other).
In the 4+1 case, **at least 6 edges need to be subdivided** (all on the side with 4 vertices).

Both cases thus yield the desired contradiction.

Comment: thank you very much for your very well explained answer. I tried to give you the points but they tell me to wait 17 more hours. I greatly appreciate your help, this subdivision subject had troubled me for a long time.

Comment: @Diane: You are very welcome. I think you will find your intuition for these problems getting better and better with time.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** Assume by contradiction that $K_{4,4}$ contains a subdivision of $K_5$.  Mark the vertices of the $K_5$ as being red.

Look at the splitting of the $8$ vertices of $K_{4,4}$ into the two bipartite groups. By the Pigeonhole principle, one of those two bipartite groups must contain at least three red vertices.

Now, the problem can be split into two cases : the case where there are three red vertices in one bipartite group (and two in the other), and the case where one bipartite group contains four red vertices (and the other contains one). In the first case, you have at least 3 connections between the red vertices in the 'loaded' bipartite group; each of these connections must go through a vertex of degree 2 from the other group.  But this is not possible (Why?). In the second case you can make a similar argument.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm kinda confused, you say each group has $4$ vertices, then you say "there is a group which contains at least three vertices from one group"?

Comment: I believe the second group is meant to be 'vertices of the $K_5$ or not'.  I.e., let the vertices of the $K_5$ be colored red; since there are $5$ of them but two groups of the $K_{4,4}$ then one of those two groups must have three red vertices.